Finding the maximum gap between binomial coefficients.
So the question is to find the maximum difference between binomial coefficients :
$\binom{n}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k}$.
I let,
$f(k)=\binom{n}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k}$
$h(k)=f(k+1)-f(k)$
we need to find the first integer $k$ for which $h(k)\leq 0$.
doing this,I get-
$k=\lceil{\frac{n-2-\sqrt{n+2}}{2}}\rceil$
but the book calculates the first value of $k$ for which $f(k)-f(k-1)\leq 0$.

doesn't this maximise $\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k-1}$?
